# if else statements being skipped, even if true

Tags: javascript

I have a basic table in javascript and a few lines of code where I compare the first values from each of the two tables. It skips the 'else if' statement and just goes straight to the 'else' at the end, when the 'else if' condition is true. I'm pretty new to all this so I won't be surprised if I messed up somewhere obvious. Any help is much appreciated.

```
var firstEquation = ['2', 'x', '+', '1', 'y', '=', '8'];
var secondEquation = ['3', 'x', '-', '1', 'y', '=', '7'];

if ( firstEquation[1] > secondEquation[1] ) {
    print("Outcome 1");
} else if ( firstEquation[1] < secondEquation[1] ) {
    print("Outcome 2");
} else {
    print("Else");
}
```

Comment: Please fix your indenting so that we can read your if chain clearly. In fact, that's probably the problem.

Comment: That's not an else if. you put else

Comment: Can I not compare strings? I'm pretty new to everything

Comment: The problem you don't compare the first value you compare the second and its `x` in both first value index is 0.

Comment: First think you need to do is learn to open the browser dev tools console (F12) and look for errors thrown. The messages will help guide you as to where invalid code issues are

Comment: @INeedAlotOfHelpPleaseAndThanks please consider accepting an answer (doesn't have to be mine) that you found helpful. Thanks! https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are comparing the second value, to compare first value use [0].
It goes straight to the last else because 'x' is not less nor greater than 'x'

Comment: Just swapped the numbers around and it worked perfectly, I'll remember that in the future. Thanks tons.

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript starts counting array indexes at 0. You've essentially said:

```
if ( "x" > "x" ) {
    print("Outcome 1");
} else if ( "x" < "x" ) {
    print("Outcome 2");
} else {
    print("Else");
}
```

Since `"x"` is the second element in each array, and `"x" = "x"`, you will always hit the else statement. Change your array indexes to `firstEquation[0]` and `secondEquation[0]` to compare the first elements of the arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you want to use `print`? That's for sending data to paper.

It's possible you mean `console.log` - which would send that output to the `console`. If you came from a language such as python, then it would make sense that you didn't realise.

Comment: Yeah I used to do very basic python while starting out, I assumed it worked the same. I'll change that now, thanks.

Comment: This really doesn't have anything to do with the question. The OP asked why the `if` statement was behaving the way it was. Whether you use `print` or `console.log()` that behavior will remain unchanged.

Comment: I disagree - the OPs problem is that his condition isn't 'evaluating'. An appropriate misdiagnosis for someone who doesn't understand what the `print` function actually does in javascript.

Comment: OP also said "It skips the 'else if' statement and just goes straight to the 'else' at the end, when the 'else if' condition is true." which implies he received output for one of his conditions, even with the `print`.

Comment: Hmm. Fair point, I must have misread it. Given that the OP sounds like they founds this helpful (as per first comment) I'm not sure it should be deleted...